# Google Geo-fencing App

Tags: android, geofencing, android-gps

I am trying for google Geo-fencing it throw error runtime:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.bipin.geofencexample, PID: 23251
                  java.lang.SecurityException: Geofence usage requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzarr$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaru.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaro$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaro$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzv$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaai.zzd(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaai.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaan.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaal.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaro.addGeofences(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaro.addGeofences(Unknown Source)
                      at com.bipin.geofencexample.MainActivity.onConnected(MainActivity.java:140)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzm.zzq(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaal.zzo(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaj.zzvE(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaj.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaan.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzy.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzl$1.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzj.zzwZ(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzu(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zze.zzxa(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```